# How do I return the last word of a string of text?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

If any of you have been following the progression of my questions, then this may come as no surprise.  Be that as it may, I have to ask it.  I really did attempt to find an answer to this online and got close with a few different versions of formulas, but there was always something a bit off about my formula.  Rather than muddy the waters with those failed attempts, let me explain with an image what it is I want to do.  In the image you see below:

[image]

I want to take the word that comes after "el" or "la" and return it in an adjacent column.  The entries you see above were done manually.  As you can see by the cells I have shaded purple, some don't include "el" or "la," but I don't absolutely have to have a formula that also corrects for that since there are so few of them.

I am using Excel 2007.  And, as always, thanks in advance for your knowledge, expertise, and guidance on this.  I'm always open to suggestions on how to beef up my skills with formulas and functions, too, so if you have any guidance in that respect, I won't be offended if you include it in your answer.

Comment: This is the third such question.  Why not try and find the answer.  Never a bad time to figure out the proper question to put into google. I put your title in google with `excel` at the end and a whole list of answers came up.

Comment: Here is your answer on stackoverflow [`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ", 100)), 100))`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9526808/935614). I already confirmed the solution with your examples. Give it an upvote. It's a very clever one

Comment: Which is something which may or may not work. The LENgth 100 part may fail in some edge cases.   LEN of the string might be better. Or give up as a worksheet function and use VBA.

Comment: @Scott Craner.  Actually, I did try to find the answer and experimented with a couple of formulas, to no avail. When I was younger, I used to spend gobs of time trying to figure out something all on my own, much to the criticism and perhaps even exasperation of others.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Now I don't.  In a world where rewards seem to go to those who can get the answers the quickest, regardless of how they come by them, it sometimes pays to work smarter and not harder.  So, now I spend a certain amount of time trying to find the answer on my own.  When I don't find one within that time frame, I throw it out to others while I work on something else.  It is a much more efficient use of my time.

Comment: @nixda  Thank you for the suggestion.  I haven't tried it out yet but will do so soon.

Comment: @nixda  Worked like a charm.  None of the formulas I was experimenting with were exactly like that and it probably would have taken me at least a week to have discovered which one among the hundreds of variations in existence would be one that I needed.  Not only are you quick, but you are brilliant for even just finding it.  I followed your suggestion and tried to upvote it, but I don't have enough street cred for it to count.  Nevertheless, I'll be sure to check out that StackExchange in the future.  Again, thank you.

Comment: As for StackExchange protocol, does anyone know how I proceed from here in terms of closing this question out?  I want to leave it intact so that someone with a similar question can be directed to the right answer, which is titled, **"How can I perform a reverse string search in Excel without using VBA?"**  I don't know that those with a lower level of spreadsheet sophistication would think to phrase it quite like that and the text within that thread isn't likely to make it surface in search terms an "unsophisticated" user would use.

Comment: @LisaBeck The usual way is to accept the answer which solves your problem. There is no "close" button since another person can always come up with a better solution in the future. If no answer is given and you found a solution in the meantime, you can post it as an answer directly below your question and accept your own answer. That's totally fine. In this case I decided to post it as community wiki so I don't get credit/points for someone else 's work

Comment: I know we're not supposed to add thank yous to these threads, but I'm sending one to @nixda as I also let it be known that I went back to the suggested answer in [**How can I perform a reverse string search in Excel without using VBA?"**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba).  I have enough "street cred" now, so I was able to upvote it.  Again, thank you for your help, nixda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last word:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ", 100)), 100))
```

To get the first word:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ", 100)), 100))
```

These formulas [substitute](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/substitute.php) every space with [100 spaces](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rept.php) and then return the [last](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/right.php) (or [first](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php)) 100 characters. The [TRIM function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php) removes the unwanted white spaces.

---

Edge cases where this would not work

- Input string has more than ~300 white spaces. The exact number
  depends on how long the rest of the input string is. The limiting
  factor is the allowed maximum of 32767 characters in an Excel cell
- Last single word is longer than 100 characters since the RIGHT function only returns the last 100 characters and would therefor cut off longer words. Same applies to the second formula

<sub>Source: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba/9526808#9526808)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The 07/18/2016 answer did not work for me, missing some entries. However, this one did:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1), " ", REPT(" ", LEN(TRIM(A1)))), LEN(TRIM(A1))))
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16868040/3171509