# Extract last word from a sentence minus any end punctuation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel worksheet with sentences (50 total), all in different rows. I have to extract the last word in each sentence, excluding punctuation.  The sentences have different numbers of characters. First sentence is “Mary plays the piano.”

[image: Excel Problem]

I have accomplished it using 2 different cells. One cell `=RIGHT(J1,6)` takes out `piano.` The next cell references that one and is `=Substitute(S1,"."," ")` which takes out the period.

I would like to combine the 2 in one cell and be able to auto fill all 50 sentences. The other sentences are not the same number of characters and have different punctuation.  What is a formula that would work for this?  I am assuming a substitution formula along with a `RIGHT`?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? What results did you get? Can you share some example data? :)

Comment: There’s 50 sentences total all in different rows.  First sentence is Mary plays the piano.  I have accomplished it using 2 different cells.  One cell =RIGHT(J1,6) takes out piano. The next cell references that one and is =Substitute(S1,”.”,” “) which takes out the period.   I would like to combine the 2 in one cell and be able to auto fill all 50 sentences.  The other sentences are not the same # of characters and have different punctuation

Comment: That is useful information to someone answering your question, please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1330965/edit) to include it. Thanks!

Comment: VBA function (macros in Excel's term) is safe?

Comment: Yes it is safe.

Comment: `"I have accomplished it using 2 different cells."` Accomplished what? What are you trying to do to the 50 sentences?

Comment: Sorry I edited the post and erased that part...trying to extract the last word minus the punctuation at the ends

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you want to do with that last word, but wouldn't it be easier to first convert those rows into columns for each part of the sentence, separated by the spaces and punctuation, and then do what you want to that last word?

Comment: An answer to the first half of your problem can be found here: https://superuser.com/q/1102448/76571

Comment: I have put an image of the problem in the original question. Maybe this will clear things up. Thanks for the comments guys. I am still pretty new to excel so any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Khris85 have you tried my proposed solution?

Comment: I did but no luck.  Kept saying it was an error

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely on the right track with the `RIGHT()` and `SUBSTITUTE()` functions.

Let's walk through the process of generalising and combining the formulas.

For this, we'll work with the sentence `What to do?` in `A1`, your `RIGHT()` formula in `B1`, and your `SUBSTITUTION()` formula in `C1`. Thus, your formulas would be `=RIGHT(A1,3)` and `=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"?","")`:

[image: Workbook Screenshot]

#### Step 1

We need to generalise:

```dart
<1> RIGHT(A1,3)
```

The `3`, which is the length of the last word including any following punctuation, needs to be modified to work with any sentence. One way to do that is to realise that the last word length can be calculated from the length of the sentence and the one-based index of the last space.

For our example, the length is 11 and the index of the last space is 8,

```
What to do?
       ↑  ↑
12345678  11
```

and 11 - 8 → 3

The length can be calculated with:

```dart
<2> LEN(A1)
```

The index is a bit trickier, as `FIND()` can only be used to find the index of the first space, not any other one. However, we can use `SUBSTITUTE()` to help out as it *does* allow us to substitute any specific space. If we change the last space to a character that doesn't exist elsewhere in the sentence, we could *then* use `FIND()` to find it, and thus the index.

The formula to do the substitution is

```dart
<3>  SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","§",2)
```

where `2` is the occurrence number of the last space, i.e. the 2nd space, and hopefully `§` doesn't exist.

We can then use `<3>` to find the index of the last space like so:

```dart
<4>  FIND("§",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","§",2))
```

But how do we work out the `2`? That's a little tricky. Notice that the occurrence number of the last space in the sentence is the same as the *count* of the spaces in the sentence.

The count can be calculated by removing the spaces from the sentence. That reduces its length by the count. From this and the original length, we can obtain the count:

```dart
<5>  LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))
```

Plugging this back into `<4>` leads to the formula for the index of the last space:

```dart
<6>  FIND("§",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","§",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))
```

Subtracting this from `<2>` leads to the length of the last word:

```dart
<7>  LEN(A1)-FIND("§",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","§",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))
```

Plugging `<7>` back into `<1>` leads to the generalised

```dart
<8>  RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("§",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","§",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))))
```

**Step 2**

We need to generalise:

```dart
<9> SUBSTITUTE(B1,"?","")
```

Now, since `SUBSTITUTE()` returns the unmodified target string if the search string can't be found in it, we can "chain" more than one of this function to remove multiple possible punctuation characters. For example, to also remove a `!` we would do this:

```dart
<10> SUBSTITUTE(<9>,"!","")
```

Plugging `<9>` into `<10>` gives:

```dart
<11> SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"?",""),"!","")
```

Since there are only three punctuation characters at the end of a sentence, `?`, `!`, and `.` (I hope), `<10>` can be fully generalised to this:

```dart
<12>  SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"?",""),"!",""),".","")
```

**Step 3**

Combining the two formula is a simple matter of replacing the `B1` in `<12>` with `<8>`, which leads to the solution:

```dart
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("§",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","§",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))),"?",""),"!",""),".","")
```

---

**Notes:**

If there is no punctuation at the end of the sentence (which is the case for sentence 21 seen in your screenshot), the `SUBSTITUTE()` functions effectively do nothing and the last word is correctly returned.

If the sentences in your data set can end in some other character, say like `:`, the formula can be easily modified to cater for this.

Finally, since there is always a space between the sentence number and the first word, there is no need for error checking in the formula. It *will* however return an error if there is no sentence.

Answer (score 1):

2018 means Excel 2016 unless otherwise mentioned so `FILTERXML()` was available. It can b used in a helpful way in that if one has a well-behaved string, one can separate it into individual pieces using the delimiter that lets it be called well-behaved. The spaces between words in this case.

So that can give an array of words in each sentence. It has the feature of being able to have an individual element of the array chosen and more helpfully, one can also directly specify that the one selected be the `last()` one, so no need to count elements. That wouldn't've been hard using the `LEN()` of the string beforehand minus its `LEN()` after `SUBSTITUTE()` removed the delimiters, but still, better to not even need to do that much!

So that gets you the last word plus any punctuation. To remove the punctuation you can just take the `RIGHT()`-most character of the last word and compare it to a list of punctuation you think you  might see. Use an `IF()` wrapped around it to return a 1 for any match (one of them, obviously!) and a 2 for all failures and wrap that all with a `SUM()` that not only will give you an odd or even value, but also collapses the array the `IF()` generated into the summed value, not a passel of 2's with or without a 1. Use `MOD()` with 2 as the divisor to check even (no punctuation, or odd, and either present the output or shave the last character off with `Left()` and you have it:

```
=IF(MOD(SUM(IF(RIGHT(FILTERXML("<Outer><Inner>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</Inner><Inner>")&"</Inner></Outer>","/Outer/Inner[last()]"),1)={".",",",";"},1,2)),2)=0,FILTERXML("<Outer><Inner>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</Inner><Inner>")&"</Inner></Outer>","/Outer/Inner[last()]"),LEFT(FILTERXML("<Outer><Inner>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</Inner><Inner>")&"</Inner></Outer>","/Outer/Inner[last()]"),LEN(FILTERXML("<Outer><Inner>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</Inner><Inner>")&"</Inner></Outer>","/Outer/Inner[last()]"))-1))
```

Looks HORRIBLE, but that's just because `FILTERXML("<Outer><Inner>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</Inner><Inner>")&"</Inner></Outer>","/Outer/Inner[last()]")` occurs four times. If you replace it with "LAST" it reads much more nicely:

```
=IF(MOD(SUM(IF(RIGHT(LAST,1)={".",",",";"},1,2)),2)=0,LAST,LEFT(LAST,LEN(LAST)-1))
```

(The above doesn't work, of course, just shows the "bones" of the formula.)

See the string of punctuation in it? You just add anything you think you might encounter to that string. Or set some cells aside somewhere and enter one punctuation character after another in them, then use that range instead of the array constant like above.

Moving forward to 2021 and the `LET()` function, you could use this:

```
=LET(Punctuation,{".",",",";"},  Word,FILTERXML("<Outer><Inner>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</Inner><Inner>")&"</Inner></Outer>","/Outer/Inner[last()]"),IF(MOD(SUM(IF(RIGHT(Word,1)=Punctuation,1,2)),2)=0,Word,LEFT(Word,LEN(Word)-1)))
```

This has the advantage of being much more readable (in Excel, not here) because the `FILTERXML()` part appears only once, but also the advantage that the punctuation array appears at the very start, easy to add to if desired.

Of course, `LAMDA()` cometh, so someone may add something more soon. (I hope soon...)

Answer (score 0):

I use free Excel [RegEx Find/Replace add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) to get regular expression functionality. That makes life easier in situation like yours.

With that the formula will look like:
`=RegExReplace(A1,".* ([a-zA-Z]+)[.?!]*$","$1")`

Where:

- `=RegExReplace(A1,...)` looks in content of A1
- `.*` - for anything in the cell finished by a space
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - followed by a word (which can contain upper and lower case letters), and remembers that word
- `[.?! ]*` - followed by any number (including 0) of punctuation characters and space
- `$"` - just before the end of the cell
- `,"$1"` - then replaces the whole cell content by the word remembered.

[image]

Comment: Maybe a useful answer for future readers, but not applicable to the OP as this is an assignment. (You were not aware of this as the question has been edited to remove that information.) For the regex, I prefer to use the shorter `.* (/w+)[.?!]*$`. It works just the same for "normal" sentences, i.e. without any underscores.

Comment: @robinCTS thanks for the information! you're right `\w` (not `/`!!) is easier, but unfortunately it's not supported by all flavours of regex. As I use regex in several tools I just prefer to be sure.

Comment: Oops! Damn those typos. I must live a sheltered life - every regex engine I've used has supported `\w` (not `/w` ;-) ). Could you name a major one off the top of your head that doesn't support it?

Comment: [Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7) doesn't support it, if you consider it a major engine:) Also Tibco Spotfire. I use both of them quite often.

Comment: I was about to say that Micro$oft don't count ;-) Their "regex" search and replace is just a souped-up wildcard search and replace. I don't consider it a regex (:P) and it seems neither does M$ as they also call them wildcard searches in most places.